# Grid search CV with sklearn own estimator in python

Tags: python, search, grid, knn, imputation

I am trying to build my own estimator (regressor) and use it for imputation (KnnImputation). I'm having a problem using the grid search "GridSearchCV". 
Any ideas what is the problem?

My Code:

```
class KnnImputation(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):

    def __init__(self, k=5, distance='euclidean'):
        self.k = k
        self.distance = distance

    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'k': self.k, 'distance': self.distance}

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        self.k = parameters['k']
        self.distance = parameters['distance']

    def fit(self, X, y):

        self.xTrain = X.values
        self.yTrain = y.values

        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        ........

        return yPred

# scorer:
scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error)

kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=23)
NN = KnnImputation()
gridSearchNN = GridSearchCV(NN, param_grid=params, scoring=scorer, n_jobs=1,
                            cv=kf.split(xTrain, yTrain), verbose=1)
gridSearchNN.fit(X=xTrain, y=yTrain)
```

My Error:

```
....
  File "C:\Users\...........\dataImputation.py", line 85, in knnImputationMethod
    gridSearchNN.fit(X=xTrain, y=yTrain)
  File "C:\Users\.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 740, in fit
    self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Comment: You are asking two questions which are quite different. Please edit your question to focus on a single technical issue.

Comment: @gmds I change the header, But it's still one problem so its one question..

Comment: Is your question why you're getting this error, or why you get a printed message "more than 60 times"?

Comment: @gmds the Q is " why am I getting this error?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `sklearn` source code in `sklearn.model_selection._search`, we have the following code within the `fit` method:

```
if self.refit:
    self.best_estimator_ = clone(base_estimator).set_params(
        **self.best_params_)
    refit_start_time = time.time()
    if y is not None:
        self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
```

The important thing here is the line:

```
self.best_estimator_ = clone(base_estimator).set_params(**self.best_params_)
```

A clone is made of the `base_estimator` object, which is just your `KNNImputation` class. The instance method `set_params()` is then called on that cloned estimator. The variable `self.best_estimator` then points to the return value of `set_params()`.

In your provided code, the `set_params()` method has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`. As such, the call to `self.best_estimator_.fit()` is equivalent to `None.fit()`, which clearly won't work. You need to enable method chaining by returning `self` within the `set_params()` function.

The relevant code will be:

```
def set_params(self, **parameters):
    self.k = parameters['k']
    self.distance = parameters['distance']
    return self
```

**TL;DR:**

You need to enable method chaining in `set_params` by returning `self`.